# Parsing JSON response .

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsdata

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   response=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];}
```

Here, I get the response in the "response value" --> `[{"response":true,"danger":false}]`

The thing is: How can I rescue the "danger"(true/false) into a new variable to use it in other methods?  I need to know if "danger" is true or false becouse if its true, i have to show an alert.

I would really appreciate someone help, as I am stuck in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSJSONSerialization: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
BOOL danger=[(NSNumber*)[(NSDictionary*)[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"danger"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Only if iOS >= 5.0. Otherwise you can use one of the other JSON frameworks like JSONKit, NXJSON, YAJL or SBJSON

Comment: for me, iOS>=5.0 is the way to go today

Comment: Thank you all so much! Finally I got it!